# Android: Best way to fill Activity with new data

Tags: android, android-activity, tableview

i got the following "problem".

I want to have an activity thats shows me the standings of some teams at a specific gameday.

therefor i would add a spinner and a TableLayout. At the first Start the activity should show the standings of the actual gameday but then you can choose any other gaymeday and the standing should get updated.

Whats the best way to create this activity?

1. assemble the whole TableLayout with all TableRows and TextViews, give them ids and update those views via id during runtime. Problem: huge unflexible hardcoded layout.xml
2. assemble the layout during runtime, add ids, update via ids
3. assemble the layout during runtime. on update remove old views and create new ones
4. assemble the layout during runtime. on update restart the activity

just whant to know which one is the best. or is there any other way to achieve that

thx Cheetah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the number of views change? If no. Best way is to use the already existent views and update their values. Try to avoid recreating/reinflating views since that's an expensive task.

Comment: number of rows is a maximum of 8 so if its less i assume i just can leave some textviews blank

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd actually use a GridView with an Adapter. This will abstract away all the handling of layout changes. You just have to worry about mapping your data to appropriate views. This [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) maps ImageViews to a GridView, but there's no reason you couldn't map to TextViews containing your data in a GridView. Also, because you're using an adapter, you can take advantage of all the [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) classes and they're asynchronous loading capabilities.

In addition, using the approach will allow you program to easily adapt as your dataset changes. You may want to add more data to the table in the future and this approach will allow you to easily do that without having to constantly change your xml layouts.

Comment: +1. Don't reinvent the wheel - use a GridView or a ListView; plenty of documentation in the Android docs.

Comment: @ShibbyUK couldn't have said it better myself. That's what I'm trying to get at here. Don't reinvent the wheel.